# In wpgeodirectory how to show the current position always on the map of places?

Tags: wordpress

How can I constantly show a marker indicating my position in the map ? It is a nice feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the you are using the supreme theme:

```
a. Add the string "My current position"

        themes\supreme-directory\functions.php   Line 89 in function sd_enqueue_styles()

      Replace 
            wp_enqueue_script('supreme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/supreme.js', array(), SD_VERSION, true);

       with         
            wp_enqueue_script('supreme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/supreme.js', array(), SD_VERSION, true);
            $translation_array = array('currPosText' => __( 'My current position', 'gdlocation' ));
            wp_localize_script( 'supreme', 'phpvarsMyLocation', $translation_array );


a. Add to supreme.js not inside onready function supreme.js   at end


            //============== Show current position functions =======================

            function gdMyGeoCurrentLocation() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gdMyGeoMyCurrentLocationSuccess, gdMyGeoPositionError);
                } else {
                    gdMyGeoPositionError(-1);
                }
            }



            function gdMyGeoMyCurrentLocationSuccess(position) {
                var coords = position.coords || position.coordinate || position;
                if (coords && coords.latitude && coords.longitude) {
                    var myLat = coords.latitude,
                        myLng = coords.longitude;
                    var geoAddress = myLat + ', ' + myLng;
                    if (window.gdMaps == 'google' || window.gdMaps == 'osm') {
                        //gdMyGeoGetDirections(geoAddress);
                        gdMyGeoShowLocation(myLat, myLng);
                    }
                }
            }


            function gdMyGeoShowLocation(lt, ln) {
                if (!lt) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (window.gdMaps == 'google') {

                    var currPosMarker = jQuery.goMap.createMarker({
                        id: "-10",
                        title: phpvarsMyLocation.currPosText,
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lt, ln),
                        visible: true,
                        clickable: true
                    });

                } else if (window.gdMaps == 'osm') {

                }
            }
            //===============================


    c. In geodirectory\geodirectory-functions\map-functions\map_template_tags.php   line 172  

    change

        wp_enqueue_script('geodir-map-widget', geodir_plugin_url() . '/geodirectory-functions/map-functions/js/map.min.js',array(),false,true);

    to

        wp_enqueue_script('geodir-map-widget', geodir_plugin_url() . '/geodirectory-functions/map-functions/js/map.js',array(),false,true);


    d. Add in map.js at line 489 (function list_markers)

        // Show user current location
        gdMyGeoCurrentLocation();
```